# Is it possible to check if element 'calling' a mixin is of a specific type using LESS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

To clarify, I have a mixin:

```
.mymixin()
{
    &.myClass
    {
    }
}
```

In this mixin you can see I'm checking if the element is of class `myClass`. I'd like to do the same in principle, but rather than check if it has a class, check if it is a `li`.

This does not compile:

```
.mymixin()
{
    &li
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did some poking around but I couldn't figure it out. I tried combining it with bogus pseudo-selectors.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. There are other ways I could conditionally apply this style, I'm already passing in parameters to the mixin so could test based on the value of one of those and ensure the li's have that value, but it feels too hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. All you have to do is swap places of the parent selector `&` and the element selector:

```
.mymixin()
{
    li&
    {
    }
}
```

See [the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order) for more information.